# Onkeyup function not working with Input Name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I switch a simple input field to a choices list like this :

[image]

I use onkeyup function to get chosen name value from list with code like this :

```
<select id="sbaa8c08525_name" name="sbaa8c08525[name]" onkeyup="GetDetail(this)" class="" title="Name".....
```

and here my JS function :

```
   // onkeyup event will occur when the user 
    // release the key and calls the function
    // assigned to this event
    function GetDetail(str) {

        var e = document.getElementById("sbaa8c08525_vrstaPopisaObveznika");
        var value = e.value;
        var text = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
        

        if (str.length == 0) {
            document.getElementById("sbaa8c08525_brojObveznika").value = "";
            document.getElementById("sbaa8c08525_brojSubiekta").value = "";
            return;
        }
        else {

            // Creates a new XMLHttpRequest object
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

                // Defines a function to be called when
                // the readyState property changes
                if (this.readyState == 4 && 
                        this.status == 200) {
                      
                    // Typical action to be performed
                    // when the document is ready
                    var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

                    // Returns the response data as a
                    // string and store this array in
                    // a variable assign the value 
                    // received to the first input field
                      
                    document.getElementById
                        ("sbaa8c08525_brojObveznika").value = myObj[0];
                      
                    // Assign the value received to the
                    // last input field
                    document.getElementById(
                        "sbaa8c08525_brojSubiekta").value = myObj[1];
                }
            };

            // xhttp.open("GET", "filename", true);

            alert(str.value); // here when I fill a number with input field 
            //it give me the number, but when I make choice with choice list it not give the name chosen 

            xmlhttp.open("GET", "{{ url("rkp_fetch2") }}?rkp_id=" + str.value, true);
            
            // Sends the request to the server
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    }
```

I hope to get NAME chosen in list but alert in code don't return anything?

Comment: Please, do your best in creating a [mcve]. Currently it's hard to know exactly how are all the JS pieces related to any HTML markup since you presented none. Read [ask]. What is the exact issue you're facing? Any console errors?

Comment: I do a good example and it's work for you have a solution please? There is no error its work with number but not with name if list of choices?

Comment: Solution to what? What is `else if (text == "RKP"){` where can I test this? Are you sure `"RKP"` string is not actually a `value` ? Currently you're using `e.options[e.selectedIndex].text`

Comment: Yes you can forget RKP it work the problem is with value from a choice list

Comment: So the issue is with the `<select>`? Your select has ID `sbaa8c08525_name`. Where in the JS code are you targeting that element? I see no getELementById("sbaa8c08525_name") - Rather, I see you use `var e = document.getElementById("sbaa8c08525_vrstaPopisaObveznika");` but there's no HTML to prove that.

Comment: You're sending the wrong argument. Instead of `this`, you must set `this.value` in order to obtain the typed string by the `str` argument (or just use `this.value` inside the function).

Comment: @Roko the html code is provided by php framwork si its html generated, but with number and simple input with =out getElementById I can get it in "str" value

Comment: @Alexis88 can you explain please with code I'm beginner in JS

Comment: @Nll Just change this `onkeyup="GetDetail(this)"` for this `onkeyup="GetDetail(this.value)"` on the `<select>`.

Comment: @Alexis88 with this.vlaue is not working...

Comment: @Nll Probably because you need to use the `onchange` event. The `onkeyup` is for editable elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the desired functionality, you should use the **onchange** event instead, which is triggered when the user selects a different option. Modify your  element to include the **onchange** event handler like this:

```
<select id="sbaa8c08525_name" name="sbaa8c08525[name]" onchange="GetDetail(this)">
  <!-- Add your <option> elements here -->
</select>
```

Now, when the user selects an option from the dropdown list, the **GetDetail** function will be called, and you can retrieve the selected value and text using **str.value** and **str.options[str.selectedIndex].text**, respectively.

```
function GetDetail(str) {
  var e = document.getElementById("sbaa8c08525_vrstaPopisaObveznika");
  var value = e.value;
  var text = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

  if (str.value.length == 0) {
    document.getElementById("sbaa8c08525_brojObveznika").value = "";
    document.getElementById("sbaa8c08525_brojSubiekta").value = "";
    return;
  } else {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        document.getElementById("sbaa8c08525_brojObveznika").value = myObj[0];
        document.getElementById("sbaa8c08525_brojSubiekta").value = myObj[1];
      }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "{{ url('rkp_fetch2') }}?rkp_id=" + str.value, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
}
```